# Fill SVG path element with a background-image

Tags: html, css, image, svg, background-image

Is it possible to set a `background-image` for an SVG `<path>` element?

For instance, if I set the element `class="wall"`, the CSS style `.wall {fill: red;}` works, but `.wall{background-image: url(wall.jpg)}` does not, neither `.wall {background-color: red;}`.

Comment: Showing how to set the background image for SVG text, optionally on a per-character basis: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10853878/405017

Comment: for those looking for some more in deep info check this article [link](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-pattern-attributes/)

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You can do it by making the background into a [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns):

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image href="wall.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
```

Adjust the width and height according to your image, then reference it from the path like this:

```
<path d="M5,50
         l0,100 l100,0 l0,-100 l-100,0
         M215,100
         a50,50 0 1 1 -100,0 50,50 0 1 1 100,0
         M265,50
         l50,100 l-100,0 l50,-100
         z"
  fill="url(#img1)" />
```

[Working example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/path-pattern-fill.svg)

Comment: very nice, does this work with base64 images too? instead of wall.jpg something like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA` like you would in normal CSS?

Comment: @Christoph I don't know, try it and see.

Comment: @robertc I tried and it didn't work, but i had a duplicate style element. By eliminating it, it worked just fine;)

Comment: @robertc: I have a question regarding your answer. The pattern starts at the global coordinates (0,0). Is it possible to let the pattern use the local coordinate system from the object attached to? 
I want to draw a rect at different places in my svg and what happens is, that the pattern is repeated in the hole background and the objects are used as masks.

Comment: @TobiasKun I suggest you ask your own question.

Comment: This is a really helpful answer, especially if you're working with d3.js or other similar libs. Upvoted because damn, it saved me.

Comment: Unfortunately TCPDF doesn't support SVG Patterns, as I imagine other programs which don't yet have full SVG2 support don't either.

Comment: @robertc please update your answer to mention that `xlink:href` is deprecated since SVG 2 and to simply use `href` now. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href