# Fill SVG element with with a background-image with an offset

Tags: html, css, image, svg, background-image

I want to do something similar to this [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

However, I want to shift/offset the image. With CSS, it can easily done by setting `background-image` and `background-position`. How do I do it with SVG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `patternTransform` on the pattern element to transform the pattern; it works just like the `transform` attribute you may already be familiar with. See [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#PatternElementPatternTransformAttribute) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `pattern` and a SVG element with the `fill` attribute.

Here is an example: insert an image at position (10, 10) with a (40, 550) offset and a size (420, 340). Note that you must set the correct `x`/`y` and `transform="translate(-x1 -y2)"`.

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://i.imgur.com/MQHYB.jpg">Original image</a>
</p>

<svg version="1.1" width="500" height="400" style="background-color: #EEE;">
  <defs>
<pattern id="europe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
         width="1456px" height="1094px">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/MQHYB.jpg"/>
</pattern>
  </defs>

  <rect fill="url(#europe)" transform="translate(-30 -540)" 
    x="40" y="550" width="420" height="340"/>
</svg>
```