# How can I make an image interactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've been trying to figure out how to make a picture have different points where the user can click on one and it will display a description.
It's the same concept as an interactive map, just it's not a map, it's just a picture. The image would be for a website.

Something similar to this codepen (http://codepen.io/ scarl3tt/details/jEBmyG) but i can't get it to work with a different image.

I'm not fluent in either CSS, HTML or JS. However, I am fairly good with both CSS and HMTL.

So I'm wondering, how would I code it? OR is there a tool that generates the code automatically?

Thanks in advance
Joe

Comment: You can use an imagemap:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Position some elements over the image (most likely with absolute positioning) and attach a click event to them - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/986m7oop/)

Comment: You said you tried to get the codepen example work with a different image  but with no success, can you what you've tried on codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: All your answers have been awesome cheers Jonathan, Eskimo and Antonio!

Answer (score 4):

You should create an [image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) using the [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) and [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) tags

There are lots of generators available online too, just do a [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Image%20Map%20Generator)

You can also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8971815/5618881) for more tools used to create Image Maps

Comment: Thanks! That other questions is very helpful, cheers man!

Answer (score 2):

With your skills you should use [htmlmaps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and catch the basic behavior via simple js id-hover/onclick catching.

The useful generators for maps can be found in google.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks Daniel:)

Comment: I recommend JQuery and .find on document ;)