# Add markers to an image using javascript (different from the other post)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, marker

I am aware there is a post with a similar title but I am not trying to achieve the same thing. I am trying to achieve something similar to what this website is doing - https://www.commuterclub.co.uk/

**(scroll down to the section where is says "Helping commuters across the UK get a better commute")**

I am getting information from a JSON api providing me with X and Y coordinates and some text, I want to populate an image with a circle (respresent the x & y coordinates) and a bubble with the text using javascript like in the commuter club website.

I found a plugin - http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Adding-Notes-Markers-To-An-Image-imgNotes.html - and i was able to plot the image with markers and a tooltip but not what i am trying to achieve.

***EDIT***

I have used the above plugin to put the markers on my image and make them disappear and reappear randomly. see code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var $img = $("#image").imgNotes({
                onShow: $.noop,
                onAdd: function() {
                        this.options.vAll = "bottom";
                        this.options.hAll = "middle";
                        var elem =     $(document.createElement('div')).addClass("mrkr").css({
                                                                        "background-color": "#9AB54D",
                                                                        height: "8px",
                                                                        width: "8px",
                                                                        "border-radius": "60px",
                                                                        "text-align": "center",
                                                                        color: "#fff"
                                                                    }).attr("title", "");
                        var self = this;
                        $(elem).tooltip({
                                content: function() {
                                            return $(elem).data("note");
                                        }
                        });
                        return elem;
                } 
    });
            $(".mrkr").tooltip().tooltip("open");
    $img.imgNotes("import", [   {x: "0.5", y:"0.5", note:"Text 1"}, 
                                {x: "0.322", y:"0.269", note: "Text 2"},
                                {x: "0.9", y:"0.6", note: "Text 3"},
                                {x: "0.1", y:"0.456", note: "Text 4"},
                                {x: "0.345", y:"0.987", note: "Text 5"},
                                {x: "0.824", y: "0.593", note: "Text 6"}]);

    var divs = $('.viewport').find('.mrkr'),
len = divs.length,
randomDiv,
speed = 2000;
var interval = setInterval(
            function() { 
                    randomDiv = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
                    divs.removeClass('show');
                    divs.eq(randomDiv).addClass('show');                         
            } , speed);
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I want to show all 4 markers at a given time and as a new one appears one of the older one fades out.

Javascript isn't my strongest language so all the help you can give will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The provided example is a google map which includes extensive tooling to achieve this kind of thing. Are you also using a map or is this a generic query for overlaying images with interactive features?

Comment: *"not what i am trying to achieve"* ... well how would we know what the difference is? Question is far too broad to fit this site's guidelines as it currently stands as per [help]

Comment: @Yoda - I am using an Image, I know the example is using Google maps but I wondered if it was possible to create something like that using an Image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975288/how-can-i-make-an-image-interactive

Comment: @charlietfl - Sorry I thought I was clear, I want to be able to create something similar to the commuter club website. Showing information from a JSON api.

Comment: @geekysneaks fine but that isn't a specific code related problem , it is a broad concept and that is not how this site works. Read through the help link provided. This isn't a *"how to"* tutorial site. Had you provided some code based on plugin showing what you currently have and explained in better detail what it should do....that would be possibly an appropriate question

Comment: @charlietfl okay, I will edit and expand on the code I have.

Comment: Do note however that if the plugin docs and features don't support what you want then modifying the plugin itself would also be too broad

Comment: @charlietfl - updated it. hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

so you can **Iterate** through **List of Data** items you received at **Intervals** and show one or two pins at a time.

prepend the bubble (html and css) in a string and pass it to **createElement** each time you show a new pin, and remove the old bubble element from the DOM.

Comment: How would you go about starting this, my javascript is very junior