# Repeated pattern in a Raphael element

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, background-image, raphael

Is there a way to have a repeated pattern as the background to a Raphael element?

In particular, can I overlay a semi-transparent .png on top of the fill colour? (or an alternative might be to have a clip-path (not rect) for an image)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the SVG solution to having a repeater pattern as background. You can work your way from there.

First of all create a [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns) and in that pattern put the [image](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) you want to repeat. Give an ID to that pattern and use that ID as an [IRI in the `fill` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) of your shape that needs tiling.

To also have a default background you only need to have another identical shape behind it with the background you'd like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 400" 
    version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="myTile" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"
             viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
      <image x="0" y="0" width="20px" height="20px" xlink:href="tile.png" />
    </pattern> 
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" fill="Red" width="800" height="400">
  </rect>
  <ellipse fill="url(#myTile)" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"  
        cx="400" cy="200" rx="350" ry="150" />
</svg>
```

*Warning: Running the example above may hurt your eyes.*

Comment: This looks great - I won't be able to try it out yet though as my boss tells me the pattern fill can wait til later

Comment: Update - raphael v2 now supports background images http://jsfiddle.net/wheresrhys/7NXbw/