# Box2djs, JS Physics Engine - Setting a background image for ball objects?

Tags: jquery, css, image, box2d, physics-engine

Working with the Box2djs plugin here:
http://www.crackin.com/dev/mms/physics/

... and all I'm trying to do is fill the ball objects with an image texture. I was hoping it was as simple as setting a css value, but I don't seem to be doing it right as none of the standard background related css rules change the balls. Using a math.random I could create 5 distinct class names to apply to each ball to create the different textured objects.

Here's an example of what it looks like now, compared to something I could make them look like using images:
[M&M Mock Image](http://www.crackin.com/dev/mms/physics/mms_mock.jpg)

This is the specific build of the physics engine I'm using this ...
github.com/hrj/box2d-js ... which is using jQuery instead of Prototype.

Comment: Found this thread here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

...but my attempts to define an image as a pattern then apply that pattern to the balls hasn't worked so far. I also don't quite understand what the responder in that thread is doing with the second bit (apparently calling the pattern and applying it to the svg object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing with Box2DJS a lot and think I've found everything I need to implement it for almost anything (e.g. collision detection hooks, etc). Here is a snippet of code that I wrote to integrate a box or circle image in place of a box or circle object:

```
if ( myBallImage )
    {
    for ( aBody = world.m_bodyList; aBody != null; aBody = aBody.m_next )
        {
        var jellyObject = aBody.GetUserData();
        if ( typeof(jellyObject) != "object" || jellyObject == null )
            continue;

        var position = aBody.GetCenterPosition();
        var angle = aBody.GetRotation();
        var mass = aBody.GetMass();
        var halfheight = 0;
        var halfwidth = 0;

        for ( aShape = aBody.GetShapeList(); aShape != null; aShape = aShape.m_next )
            {
            halfheight = aShape.GetHalfHeight();
            halfwidth = aShape.GetHalfWidth();
            }

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate( position.x, position.y );
        ctx.rotate( angle );
        ctx.translate( -halfwidth, -halfheight );   // halfwidth, halfheight

        if ( jellyObject.shape == "MYBALL" )
            ctx.drawImage(myBallImage, 0, 0, halfwidth*2, halfheight*2 );
        else
        if ( jellyObject.shape == "MYBOX" )
            ctx.drawImage(myBoxImage, 0, 0, halfwidth*2, halfheight*2 );

        ctx.restore();
        }
    }
else
    {
    myBallImage = new Image();
    myBallImage.src = 'circle.gif';

    myBoxImage = new Image();
    myBoxImage.src = 'box.gif';
    }
```

Comment: I'd moved on from this project and just came back to see you replied a few months ago. Thanks a million! This looks like exactly what I need... when I finally have a chance to get back to that project.