# Add a background image (.png) to a SVG circle shape

Tags: html, css, svg

Is this possible?  The following is what I tried but it completely fills the circle with black.

```
<svg id='vizMenu' width="700" height="660">
    <defs>
        <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
            <feOffset dx="0.5" dy="0.8" result="offsetblur"/> 
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <circle id='top' filter="url(#dropshadow)" cx="180" cy="120" r="80" stroke="#2E2E2E" stroke-width="2" fill="url('images/word-cloud.png')"/>
    <circle id='bottom' filter="url(#dropshadow)" cx="500" cy="300" r="80" stroke="#2E2E2E" stroke-width="2" fill="url('images/word-cloud.png')"/>
    <circle id='extra' filter="url(#dropshadow)" cx="180" cy="560" r="80" stroke="#2E2E2E" stroke-width="2" fill="#ffffff"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Haha there are lots of them, I think they feel strong hiding behind their computers. Good luck with your problem

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but perhaps it's because the code you posted is for applying a dropshadow, not an image fill!

Comment: Nevermind, the non-working code for fill is offscreen. When posting code try to reduce it to the minimum.

Comment: You can't reference a PNG directly from a fill or stroke attribute at the moment. You'll have to wrap the image in a pattern element and define how it should be tiled and scaled. See the answer from [Duopixel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11500364/109374).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An image fill for an svg element is achieved through [SVG Patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns)...

```
<svg width="700" height="660">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1">
      <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="url.png"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle id='top' cx="180" cy="120" r="80" fill="url(#image)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is possible to do with SVG filters too, but patterns is the natural answer.

Comment: Can we stop replicate png display in background using fill. In this case it will keep replicating the image in background. Is it possible to display pattern only once? I mean no tiling...

Comment: closing defs tag missing

Comment: I closed that tag for you

Comment: Is there a way to stop the pattern from repeating, having it scale to fit instead?

Comment: This technique doesn't work at all. You HAVE to use the method in [Teo Inke's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2105657/teo-inke) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape#answer-24128191).  And even then, that breaks when you try to transform in any way (i.e. scaling, etc).

Answer (score 32):

Well, I couldn't make it work with the accepted answer. This is how I ended up doing it:

```html
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="image" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100" width="100">
          <image x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7Nlcay7.jpg"></image>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <circle id='top' cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#image)"/>
    </svg>
```

If you want to customize the size, use this as a scale reference:

x = yourPreferredSize

```
<svg width=">2x" height=">2x">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height=">2x" width=">2x">
      <image x="0" y="0" height="2x" width="2x" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7Nlcay7.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle id='top' cx="x" cy="x" r="x" fill="url(#image)"/>
</svg>
```

(This scale works for squared images)

Comment: Even I couldn't get it working with the accepted answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How do I stop it from repeating? also it's not scalling properlly

Comment: DIscovered that the key to centering my image in a circle was to set `x` and `y` attributes on the `<pattern>` to half the width/height ("x" above). Still haven't found an explanation for why the `<pattern>'s` width/height have to exceed the image's dimensions to eliminate borders (padding?), but that has been my experience as well.

Answer (score 17):

[Image repetition problem solved with proper explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883994/crop-to-fit-an-svg-pattern) (Thanks to AmeliaBR)

TL;DR: The concept of `objectBoundingBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` are used!

```
<svg height = "10%" width = "10%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id = "attachedImage" height = "100%" width = "100%"            
                   patternContentUnits = "objectBoundingBox">
       <image xlink:href = "url.png" preserveAspectRatio = "none" 
              width = "1" height = "1"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
<circle cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "35%" fill = "url(#attachedImage)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but I used a filter to overlay the image. The above solution didn't work for me because of scaling and it seemed like the images was tiled. I used this instead, I hope it will help others as well.

```
<svg width="700" height="660">
    <filter id="this_image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <feImage xlink:href="test_image.png"/>
    </filter>
    <circle filter="url(#this_image)" cx="180" cy="120" r="80" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this works but image is coming in rectangle? circle should be filled entirely  with bg image.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, the differences are that this doesn't use the `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` and that you specify the desired width and height of the image element.

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="{some name}" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <image href="{image url}" x="0" y="0" width="{desired width}" height="{desired height}"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. I couldn't see the image. I use the debugging and it clearly showed me the image was in good position but nothing to display and I verified that my image was an valid image.