# How can I replace an SVG shape with an image?

Tags: javascript, svg

Given an SVG like the one from this [Google Visualization Example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?csw=1#markersexample), there are circles drawn on the svg like this:

```
<circle cx="448.0843694002127" cy="236.6677163333033" r="12" stroke="#cccccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#0000ff"/>
```

I tried using firebug to manually replace that with a sample image at the same x/y coordinates, so for instance replacing the above code with:

```
<img width="50px" height="50px" cy="135.71439117815066" cx="343.43783232923863" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png/320px-Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png">
```

But that doesn't work (nothing seems to render properly). I thought perhaps using cx/cy was the issue, so I tried switching those to just regular x/y properties:

```
<img width="50px" height="50px" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png/320px-Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png" x="343.43783232923863" y="135.71439117815066">
```

Again, no-go.

I tried the technique used here:

[Does SVG support embedding of bitmap images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images)

But again, it didn't render the image in the SVG.

I checked all over Stack Overflow, but found information only on how to tile a circle with an image:

[Add a background image (.png) to a SVG circle shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape)

This has its own set of images as the pattern just tiles and can't be resized for each shape.

Is there any reliable way of doing this? Ideally, I want to loop through each circle and replace it with an image that will be sized to the circle it replaces.

I downloaded the SVG and added the image manually, but I get the following error:

> XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
>
> Location: (removed
>   for privacy)
>
> Line Number 2, Column 1:`<image width="50px"
>   height="50px" y="135.71439117815066" x="343.43783232923863"
>   xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png/320px-Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png">`
>
> ^

Answer (score 1):

The element you want is `<image>` not `<img>`.

And the attributes `cx` and `cy` are meaningless on `<image>` elements. You can use `x` and `y` instead (like in your second attempt), and note that you are required to specify a non-zero `width` and `height` on the `<image>` element (again like in your second attempt). See the [svg spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#ImageElement) for the details.

Comment: Apparently firebug was changing my `<image>` in to `<img>` causing much gnashing of teeth. However, when I moved the SVG to a text file and saved as SVG and then made the change, I get `XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace` on this line `<image width="50px" height="50px" y="135.71439117815066" x="343.43783232923863" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png/320px-Flag_of_Fukuyama%2C_Hiroshima.png">` with or without trailing slash. It is in a group element, is this a problem?

Comment: You need to define the `xlink` namespace. Make sure you are including `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` in your root `<svg>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a mask using an image.  The draw the circle or any other graphics referencing the mask.