# Why is this background image not working for this SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I want to create this triangular/polygonal shape using SVGs and assign it a background image.

```
    <svg class="svg-graphic" width="100%" height="100%" class="svg-graphic" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
        <defs>
            <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1">
              <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/fe6e34ef00254f2bd05451f525b02324/tumblr_mw8osqc77F1qdrz3yo3_500.jpg"></image>
            </pattern>
        <polygon points="0, 0, 100, 0, 50, 50" fill="url('http://25.media.tumblr.com/fe6e34ef00254f2bd05451f525b02324/tumblr_mw8osqc77F1qdrz3yo3_500.jpg')"/>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Very similar to this question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape)

Happy Chanukkah

Answer (score 0):

The `fill` attribute references the pattern, in your case it's `url(#image)` (like you'd do in CSS). Repeating the image's URL is pointless there. See the accepted answer in the question you linked to.

Apart from that you must make sure, that the view box spanned by the `<pattern>` actually matches the shape it shall be applied to. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/k7Rk9/12/

Comment: It should be left as fill="url(#image)"?

Comment: And moved out of the `<defs>` element, yes. Content of `<defs>` is invisible, like HTML's `<head>`. You had that correct, when I wrote the answer.

Comment: Yeah that's not working - and now that I double check, neither is the answer to the question I referenced. http://jsfiddle.net/k7Rk9/11/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fill="#url"

you have to give the polygon/path a class and then from that class, assign the background image (that's already defined in the defs):

```
    .imageFill {
      fill: url(#image);
    }
```

Comment: Nope. Both are equivalent, if you use the right syntax for the `fill` attribute: `fill="url(#image)"`. That is, CSS will overwrite the attribute, if both are present, but otherwise they're the same.