# SVG <pattern> <image> does not scale in Firefox when used on <path>

Tags: firefox, svg, path, stretch

**Example [here](http://codepen.io/jmarkevicius/pen/vOKQEO)**

```
<svg width="978px" height="668px" viewBox="0 0 978 668" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="top" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 717 478" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image xlink:href="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" width="717px" height="478px"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <g>        
    <path d="M1,95.0771484 L1,0 L979,0 L424.030762,379.068604 L1,95.0771484 Z" fill="url(#top)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Open in Firefox to see image stretched (undesired effect)

Open in Chrome to see image sliced (desired effect)

I read [Crop to fit an svg pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883994/crop-to-fit-an-svg-pattern), which was close to solving the problem.

It appeared to work only on 'circle's #2 and #3.

When I applied my 'path', image got stretched again.

They mention a Firefox bug, but it is marked as 'fixed'.

How can I get my image sliced across browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed from Firefox 40 onwards by [bug 1047973](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1047973). I think that's currently available as [Firefox developer edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#developer) but will be out in the production version on 11th August 2015

Comment: Thanks Robert. Is there any kind of workaround before August?

Comment: I mean, in terms of web development. Is there a patch (js perhaps?) that would simulate the fix to the end user?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, you could try adjusting the patternTransform to scale the pattern dynamically as the page resizes I guess. Of course you'd have to ensure you only did that in Firefox versions prior to 40.

Comment: or maybe applying a clipPath to an image that's directly rendered (no pattern required then)

Comment: I like the idea of clipPath, which I initially eliminated as it doesn't have great browser support. This could work as a temporary patch. Thanks.

Comment: Really? AFAIK every UA supports clipPath so I don't know where you're getting your information from.

Comment: That's about clipping non-SVG objects and also covers non-URL syntax. You're using the older url syntax and applying it to SVG objects, that works fine most places, even IE.