# Fill parttern (bitmap) in SVG is flipped and mirrored

Tags: svg

I want to fill a SVG path completely with a jpg or png image. I found this answer very useful ( [Crop to fit an svg pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883994/crop-to-fit-an-svg-pattern) ) but this doesn't seem to work for more complex paths. It does for rect and circles :-). When applying this code to a path it shows the jpg images upside down and mirrored. In several browsers.

This behaviour can be seen at http://www.paulvanroekel.nl/specials/colourmyvm/test.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the convention is that with raster images y increases as you go down the page, with vector images y increases as you go up the page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing unnessecary scale and transform code and by changing the coordinates for "M" (absolute) to "m" relative. That did the trick. Basically I edited the svg file again in Inkscape and saved it als normal SVG.