# clip-path in IE or alternative ways to create a skew lines design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a one page html page below design (this is simplified version on main design. the main design is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUCLy.jpg) ).

[image]

As you see there are three section (or more) that created by a div(or any other block-level element).

The bottom edge of each div is made of three connected line (two of them are diagonal and another is solid).

In each section can insert any html content and background-color of them is not specified and can different.

I searched many on the web and found that to create clipped div(box) should I use `clip-path` new css property. that's awesome for this purpose but it is very new and some of browsers (in their older versions) and IE (that is important for me) does not supported.

Even, by [Clippy tools](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/), I created a simple design of a section that you can see on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ahmadbadpey/pen/jryzYX).

Can I use SVG to make this scheme if yes, how?

Can anyone help me that How can I design this scheme where been supported in major browsers.

**Update:**
I change the design picture for More clarity

Comment: https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath

Comment: tnx,But can you explain how to use it? where is it's documentation? did you use it before? does it support IE versions?

Comment: Which IE versions do you need to support?

Comment: @LGSon, minimum version of IE that can implement this scheme .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

Comment: Voted to close as dupe as it will most likely be the best answer to your question. Here is one more post that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape

Comment: Searching the web using "svg shape with image" gave me those links and then some ... and as CSS shapes does not work cross browser, SVG will be the best second choice