# How to add a border to an image inside an SVG circle

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, geometry, gsap

I am animating a stroke around a circle using GSAP. Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/pGRPrm).

What I want to do is have spacing between the outer pink and (what should be) the inner circular image, like this:

[image]

Here's my SVG code:

```
      <svg id='svg1' width='48' height='48' viewBox='0 0 48 48'>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='24' r='22' fill='none' stroke='#FF62E1' strokeWidth='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
          xlinkHref={'https://source.unsplash.com/random'}
          clipPath='url(#circleView)'
          />
        <circle
          cx='24'
          cy='24'
          r='22'
          fill='none'
          stroke='#FF62E1'
          strokeWidth='2'
          strokeDasharray='100.48'
          strokeDashoffset='100.48'
          // @ts-ignore
          ref={(circle) => { this.circle = circle }} >
          >
        </circle>
      </svg>
```

I have played around with [`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape) and using multiple circles to create the effect, but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You need a bigger radius for the second circle. If you change the radius you will need to recalculate the length of the path for stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset. You will also need to recalculate the size of your SVG canvas

Comment: @enxaneta or smaller clipPath circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the radius on your clipPath circle to be a little bit less than the other circle and use a square image so it fits perfectly.

```
render() {
  return (
    <svg id='svg1'  viewBox='0 0 48 48'>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id='circleView'>
          <circle cx='24' cy='24' r='18' fill='none' stroke='#FF62E1' strokeWidth='2' />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <image
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width='48'
        height='48'
        xlinkHref={'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1500x1500/'}
        clipPath='url(#circleView)'
      />
      <circle
        cx='24'
        cy='24'
        r='22'
        fill='none'
        stroke='#FF62E1'
        strokeWidth='2'
        // @ts-ignore
        ref={(circle) => { this.circle = circle }} >
      </circle>
    </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/OdWgQL)

This option leaves a transparent gap where the background can be seen, so may or may not be exactly what you want. The alternative is to create another circle with a stroke but no fill on top with a different radius again.

[Alternative Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/WPRZEL)

Comment: Thanks @ksav, I was away for a week but this has helped me greatly. Much appreciated!