# How convert svg to png (in bash or nodejs) with background raster image?

Tags: node.js, bash, svg

I insert background image to svg like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape) Now I need convert it to png on server side. I try bash command:

```
 convert -density 1200 march.svg march.png
```

In result I see svg only without background raster image. Also I try [npm svg-to-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-to-png) and also not see background.

How I can resolve this issue? Thanks!

**UPD:**

[Downliad march.svg](https://mail.dolodom.com/sendimg/admin/march.svg)

Comment: Add march.svg to your question.

Comment: Cirus, thanks, I did it

Answer (score 0):

Requires `inkscape` installed, but in Node.js you can have a function like this one:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
  
/*
*  Requires:
*   
* > brew install inkscape
*/
async function convertSvgToFormat(svg: string, format: Format): Promise<Buffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const id = crypto.randomUUID();
    const input = `in_${id}.svg`;
    const output = `out_${id}.${format}`;
    const command = `inkscape --export-type=${format} ${input} --export-filename=${output}`;
    const clear = () => [input, output].forEach((file) => fs.unlinkSync(file));

    fs.writeFileSync(input, svg);

    spawn(command, { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' })
      .on('close', (out) => {
        if(out !== 0) reject()
        else resolve(fs.readFileSync(output));
        clear();
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
        clear();
      });
  });
```

To use it:

```js
const pngBuffer = await convertSvgToFormat('<svg><text>Test</text><svg>', 'png')
```

All supported formats of `inkscape`:

```
type Format =
  | 'dxf'
  | 'emf'
  | 'eps'
  | 'fxg'
  | 'gpl'
  | 'hpgl'
  | 'html'
  | 'jpg'
  | 'odg'
  | 'pdf'
  | 'png'
  | 'pov'
  | 'ps'
  | 'sif'
  | 'svgz'
  | 'tar'
  | 'tex'
  | 'tiff'
  | 'webp'
  | 'wmf'
  | 'xaml'
  | 'zip';
```