# Centered background image within SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to add a centered image inside SVG.

It will serve as a user avatar but failing to do so

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1f1b33;
  padding: 2rem;
}

svg {
width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 121.375 125.397">
      <g
        id="blank"
        transform="translate(-1460.94 -927.887)"
      >
        <path
          id="wrapper"
          data-name="Caminho 2257"
          d="M80.617,78.013C67.787,91.6,11.606,90.985-8.689,69.872s-20.527-73.915,0-90.659S66.834-47.3,87.13-26.188,93.447,64.424,80.617,78.013Z"
          transform="translate(1484.938 966.119)"
          fill="#fff"
          opacity="0.2"
        />
        <rect
          id="within"
          data-name="Retângulo 365"
          width="97"
          height="97"
          rx="37"
          transform="translate(1475 945)"
          fill="#fff"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div
```

I already tried to create an image element inside SVG and reference it as fill, but the image is not centered.

Comment: not getting what you exactly want, you need centered `SVG` or a portion inside `SVG` to be centered?

Comment: @Zuber in `rect` instead of `fill=color` need `fill=image`

Comment: you can use `svg` as `background-image` using `css` inside a `wrapper` and use `padding`. put the `avatar image` inside that wrapper.

Comment: @Zuber you don't understand, i need the image to have the same shape as the rect, i just need to replace the color with a centered image.

Comment: see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape can help you

Comment: @Zuber As I said in my question, I already tried it, but the image is not centered.

Comment: you can use `pattern` inside `svg`

Comment: @Zuber I already tried, the image appears, but is not centered, does not fill the entire rect space.

Comment: @Yung Silva Good, helpful question.(+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pattern fill is the way to go - if your image aspect ratio is square it will work nicely. Notice the patterns width and height are the same as your rectangle. It's important in this case to set the `patternUnits` to `userSpaceOnUse` which for simplicity keeps the pattern fill from scaling to the objects bounding box.

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1f1b33;
  padding: 2rem;
}

svg {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 121.375 125.397">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="patt" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="97" height="97">
          <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/17496/flace.jpg" width="97" height="97"></image>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <g
        id="blank"
        transform="translate(-1460.94 -927.887)"
      >
        <path
          id="wrapper"
          data-name="Caminho 2257"
          d="M80.617,78.013C67.787,91.6,11.606,90.985-8.689,69.872s-20.527-73.915,0-90.659S66.834-47.3,87.13-26.188,93.447,64.424,80.617,78.013Z"
          transform="translate(1484.938 966.119)"
          fill="#fff"
          opacity="0.2"
        />
        <rect
          id="within"
          data-name="Retângulo 365"
          width="97"
          height="97"
          rx="37"
          transform="translate(1475 945)"
          fill="url(#patt)"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make an image stay in place of the color white.

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1f1b33;
  padding: 2rem;
}

svg {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="121.375"
      height="125.397"
      viewBox="0 0 121.375 125.397"
    >
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-path">
          <rect
            id="Retângulo_365"
            data-name="Retângulo 365"
            width="97"
            height="97"
            rx="37"
            transform="translate(-932 2753)"
            fill="#fff"
          />
        </clipPath>
        <pattern
          id="pattern"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          viewBox="0 0 450 450"
        >
          <image
            width="450"
            height="450"
            xlink:href="https://www.espacoluzevida.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/default-female-avatar.png"
          />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <g
        id="profile-image-customized"
        transform="translate(-152.94 -170.887)"
      >
        <path
          id="Caminho_2257"
          data-name="Caminho 2257"
          d="M80.617,78.013C67.787,91.6,11.606,90.985-8.689,69.872s-20.527-73.915,0-90.659S66.834-47.3,87.13-26.188,93.447,64.424,80.617,78.013Z"
          transform="translate(176.938 209.119)"
          fill="#fff"
          opacity="0.2"
        />
        <g
          id="Grupo_de_máscara_7"
          data-name="Grupo de máscara 7"
          transform="translate(1099 -2565)"
          clip-path="url(#clip-path)"
        >
          <path
            id="_32814145-woman-avatar-profile-picture-icon-on-light-gray-background"
            data-name="32814145-woman-avatar-profile-picture-icon-on-light-gray-background"
            d="M0,0H97V97H0Z"
            transform="translate(-932 2753)"
            fill="url(#pattern)"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An image can be inserted into any SVG shape in several ways:

1. Using clipPath
2. Using mask
3. Using pattern

With any method of inserting an image, you need to focus on the shape of the template.

If the template has a symmetrical shape, it is necessary to select the original image with the same aspect ratio.

In other words, if the cropping pattern is a circle or regular polygons, then you need to select images with the same width and height.

### Using mask

I chose a square image

[image]

```css
.body {
  
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color:#1f1b33;
}

svg {
width: 25%;
height:25%;
} 
image {
width:100%;
height:100%;
mask:url(#msk1);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 121.375 125.397" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <rect
          id="within"
          data-name="Retângulo 365"
     x="10" y="10"
          width="97"
          height="97"
          rx="37"
          fill="white"
    stroke="#d5d5d5"
    stroke-width="4"
        />
  </mask>
</defs> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1f1b33" />
      <g
        id="blank"
        transform="translate(-1460.94 -927.887)"
      >
        <path
          id="wrapper"
          data-name="Caminho 2257"
          d="M80.617,78.013C67.787,91.6,11.606,90.985-8.689,69.872s-20.527-73.915,0-90.659S66.834-47.3,87.13-26.188,93.447,64.424,80.617,78.013Z"
          transform="translate(1484.938 966.119)"
          fill="#fff"
          opacity="0.2"
        /> 
  </g>
        <rect
          id="within"
          data-name="Retângulo 365"
          x="10" y="10"
    width="97"
          height="97"
          rx="37"
         
          fill="none"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="2"
        />
       
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGg5.jpg" x="0" y="0"/> 
    </svg>
  </div>
```

**2.# Animation of image rotation when hovering**

CSS rules are used to implement rotation of images

```
#img {
transform-origin:125px 125px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```css
.body {
  
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color:#1f1b33;
}

svg {
width: 25%;
height:25%;
} 


#img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
mask:url(#msk1);
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 121.375 125.397" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <rect
          id="within"
          data-name="Retângulo 365"
     x="10" y="10"
          width="97"
          height="97"
          rx="37"
          fill="white"
    stroke="#d5d5d5"
    stroke-width="4"
        />
  </mask>
</defs> 
 
      <g
        id="blank"
        transform="translate(-1460.94 -927.887)"
      >
        <path
          id="wrapper"
          data-name="Caminho 2257"
          d="M80.617,78.013C67.787,91.6,11.606,90.985-8.689,69.872s-20.527-73.915,0-90.659S66.834-47.3,87.13-26.188,93.447,64.424,80.617,78.013Z"
          transform="translate(1484.938 966.119)"
          fill="#fff"
          opacity="0.2"
        /> 
  </g>
               
    <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGg5.jpg" x="0" y="0"/> 
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Zuber suggests on his comments, you can learn how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image).

Example with your code:

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1f1b33;
  padding: 2rem;
}

svg { width: 120px; }
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 121.375 125.397">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/14/21/47/dog-4476989_960_720.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g
        id="blank"
        transform="translate(-1460.94 -927.887)"
    >
      <path
          id="wrapper"
          data-name="Caminho 2257"          d="M80.617,78.013C67.787,91.6,11.606,90.985-8.689,69.872s-20.527-73.915,0-90.659S66.834-47.3,87.13-26.188,93.447,64.424,80.617,78.013Z"
          transform="translate(1484.938 966.119)"
          fill="#fff"
          opacity="0.2"
      />
      <rect
          id="within"
          data-name="Retângulo 365"
          width="97"
          height="97"
          rx="37"
          transform="translate(1475 945)"

          fill="url(#img1)"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is not occupying 100% of what the color occupied.

Comment: I must didn't understand, you asked to fill with image instead of the white didn't you? do you want it to get the whole shape?

Comment: obviously i said i need a picture instead of color, i already solved the question, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

How about using the pseudo element ::After or ::Before, setting it to relative, then giving it a background image and set your opacity or z-index to whatever you want? Just shooting a shot out there.

Comment: It's better to add some code to your answer... In this case you can edit his code in the way that you described and add it to the answer... cheers