# D3 nest an image and a circle for a node?

Tags: svg, d3.js

With d3.js force layout, what should I do if I want to nest an image and a circle for a node? Is that possible to do this with an SVG image ?

Currently I tried something like that, but it doesn't work :

```
<svg>
<g>
  <circle> ...... </circle>
  <image> ...... </image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. You can either declare the image as a pattern (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)) or use `foreignObject` to embed an HTML image.