# Jquery radar control with gradient line

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, radar-chart

Have question about jquery control - do you know where i can find (for free if it`s possible) radar jquery control that will have opportunity setup gradient for line?

It should looks like on picture [here](http://postimg.org/image/qd3f0skt7/)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**D3** is a good charting library. However it won't come with pre-made charts. You will have to do some work on your end. But on the plus side, it is free.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery and http://graves.cl/radar-chart-d3/

**Other Options:**

- http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/radar-charts/index.html
- https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/chart_gall?csw=1
- http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
- http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!RadarAreaCharts

**Gradient Line Option for D3:**

D3 uses SVG. So you could modify the fill with a gradient image. See here on how to change the fill. [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

Comment: D3 cool library, but as i understand without customizing no possible to have gradient for a line. I mean there is no solution (i tried to search before post question).

Comment: D3 uses SVG. So you could modify the fill with a gradient image. See here on how to change the fill. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Comment: The problem not in image - i need to have color gradient for all line. There is no possible to apply gradient to polygon object.