# Filling SVG Circle with image is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Setting image as background for svg circle dynamically is not working.I have done it by setting url of the image to the fill attribute of SVG circle as below.

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].setAttribute("fill", "url(#img1)");
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5RLQ/2/).

Is there any way to fill image??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5RLQ/4/):

I replaced unnecessary `setAttributeNS` calls with `setAttribute` and added important `setAttributeNS` call:

```
var circle = $('circle');

var pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
pattern.setAttribute( "id", "img1");
pattern.setAttribute( "patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
pattern.setAttribute("height", "100");
pattern.setAttribute("width", "100");
var image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
image.setAttribute("x", "0");
image.setAttribute("y", "0");
image.setAttribute("height", "100");
image.setAttribute("width", "100");
image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", 
                     "http://www.abcteach.com/free/c/circlergb.jpg");

pattern.appendChild(image);
defs.appendChild(pattern);
$(defs).insertBefore(circle);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.How does it align an image exactly in center position though x and y values are 0??.In my sample to align image in the center of circle I need to change x and y value.

Comment: Forget to mention that I have changed value of `height` and `width` image attributes to 100.