# Not able to see the background image in svg rect

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Hi I am trying to add a background image on svg rectangle. But unfortunately I am not able to see the image in the rectangle's background. My code snippet is

```
rectCanvas_o = parentElement.append("rect");
rectCanvas_o.attr("width", "30").attr("height","100%").
attr("class", this.currentAlarmClass_s);


rectCanvas_o.append("defs").append("pattern").
attr("width", 20).attr("height", 20).
attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse').append("image").
attr("width", 20).attr("height", 20).
attr("xlink:href", "image.png");
```

I also able to see my code in as html in chrome debugger as

```
<rect width="30" height="100%" class="eq__NEcontainer__currentAlarmAction">
<defs>
  <pattern width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="20" height="20" xlink:href="image.png"></image>
  </pattern>
</defs>
</rect>
```

But no background image is seen. Image location is proper. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<defs>` element only defines this pattern, it doesn't actually cause it to be rendered anywhere.  Artifacts defined in a `defs` need to be referenced by other visible elements.

In order to reference a definition you need to give it a unique id.  (Note that the defs can live anywhere in the SVG and can be referenced by any other element or elements).

```
rectCanvas_o.append("defs").append("pattern").attr("id", "my_pattern");
```

Then, you need to set the `fill` attribute of your rect to reference your defined pattern:

```
rectCanvas_o = parentElement.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "30")
    .attr("height","100%").
    .attr("class", this.currentAlarmClass_s)
    .style("fill", "url(#my_pattern)");
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that your defs is inside your rect.  Try to move it out so that the entire defs element lives at the same level as the rect element.

Comment: Hi Scott, I did that, but it didn't work either. I don't know if I am doing anything unusually silly

Comment: Here's a similar post that might help for comparison. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image.  Also, can you update your question with the final DOM snippet so we can see it all together?

Comment: Scott, Thanks first of all. It worked when I used id for pattern.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I've updated the answer based on your suggested edit.  Thanks!