# Defining a fill pattern in CSS, to be used in SVG

Tags: css, svg

How do I (or is there way to) define an SVG fill pattern in CSS, to be used in SVG? I can do this in HTML like so:

CSS:

```
.some-class-for-html {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,gibberish-goes-here==");    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="some-class-for-html">
  Blah blah blah
</div>
```

I want to do the equivalent for SVG, keeping the pattern defined in the CSS. The closest I've found is [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image), but that involves defining the fill within the SVG. I want to keep the fill defined within the CSS, the same way I'd do for HTML, and the same way I'd do for SVG colors. I've tried the following:

CSS:

```
.some-class-for-SVG {
  fill: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,gibberish-goes-here==");    
}
```

SVG:

```
<rect class="some-class-for-svg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
```

But this gets rendered without a fill. Up until now I've gotten around this by inserting the `<defs>` and `<pattern>` nodes into the SVG when it gets generated, but of course this means to change the pattern, you have to change the Javascript, which is bad.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gibberish mechanism should work. What exact gibberish are you trying?

Comment: I'm using the one generated by http://philbit.com/svgpatterns/#honeycomb

Comment: The actual fill pattern I'm using, if that matters, is: 

    url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1NiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAiPgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNTYiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiBmaWxsPSIjZjhkMjAzIj48L3JlY3Q+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yOCA2NkwwIDUwTDAgMTZMMjggMEw1NiAxNkw1NiA1MEwyOCA2NkwyOCAxMDAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2ZmZjYyOSIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIj48L3BhdGg+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yOCAwTDI4IDM0TDAgNTBMMCA4NEwyOCAxMDBMNTYgODRMNTYgNTBMMjggMzQiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2ZmZTUwMyIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIj48L3BhdGg+Cjwvc3ZnPg==");

Comment: The CSS property `background-image` doesn't work for SVG elements, because they have a fill - not a background like HTML block elements.  You could define an SVG `<pattern>` and assign that pattern to an element's fill with CSS.  Or you could use an SVG as a mask for an HTML element that has your background.

Comment: That's what I'm trying -- setting the fill property in CSS. See the last two code blocks in my original question. But that's not working for me.