# Embedding images in SVG in React

Tags: image, svg, reactjs

I am using SVG inside React, but the amount of SVG tags that ReactJS allows is  [limited](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#svg-elements) and I don't see a way to embed an `<image/>` SVG tag inside my JSX.

I've also tried using a `fill` style on a `rect` set to a url of an image, but it doesn't work either. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: SVG does not support pointing a fill to an image. You have to do it indirectly via a pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Answer (score 2):

SVG Image is now supported in 0.14.

For prior versions, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. For more about that, take a look at this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2069