# SVG clipPath with stroke

Tags: css, svg

I want to have star with border. How is it possible to show border inside clippath?

```
<svg x="0" y="0" enable-background="new 0 0 98 94" xml:space="preserve" style="position: absolute;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <polygon points="48 6 65 30 92 37 75 60 75 88 48 80 22 88 22 60 6 37 32 30" style="fill:none;stroke:#fadf0b;stroke-width:6" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Example: http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/VYdeaQ

Comment: Not sure a clip-path is what you are after...wouldn't a background to the polygon make more sense? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you can have a visible stroke on a `clipPath`, but you could `use` the star in your image as well as in the `clipPath`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPEMXd

```
 <svg x="0" y="0" enable-background="new 0 0 98 94" xml:space="preserve" style="position: absolute;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <polygon id="star" points="48 6 65 30 92 37 75 60 75 88 48 80 22 88 22 60 6 37 32 30" style="fill:none;stroke:#fadf0b;stroke-width:6" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<svg width="95" height="90" viewBox="0 0 98 94">
  <use xlink:href="#star" />
  <image style="clip-path: url(#clipping);" ... />
</svg>
```

Edit: or the other way around, with star as part of the image also used in `clipPath`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgGoxe

```
<svg width="95" height="90" viewBox="0 0 98 94">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <use xlink:href="#star" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>  
  <polygon id="star" points="48 6 65 30 92 37 75 60 75 88 48 80 22 88 22 60 6 37 32 30" style="fill:none;stroke:#fadf0b;stroke-width:6" />
  <image style="clip-path: url(#clipping);" ... />
</svg>
```