# How to Select a path in svg and apply color to the selected path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

How to Select a path in svg and apply color to the selected path ?

```js
$('#btn-test1').on("click", function() {
    $('#path1').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
});
$('#btn-test2').on("click", function() {
    $('#path2').css({ fill: "#00ff00" });
});
$('#btn-test3').on("click", function() {
    $('#path3').css({ fill: "#0000ff" });
});
$('#btn-reset').on("click", function() {
    $('#path1, #path2, #path3').css({ fill: "#ffffff" });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btn-test1">Test 1</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test2">Test 2</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test3">Test 3</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-reset">reset</button>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="path1" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M291.451,51.919v202.54c0,0,164.521,119.846,140.146,0
    C407.227,134.613,291.451,51.919,291.451,51.919z"/>

<path id="path2" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M169.595,150.844c0,0-76.24,69.615-40.606,128.309
    c35.634,58.695,155.798-51.867,151.654-85.993C276.498,159.034,177.054,89.42,169.595,150.844z"/>

<path id="path3" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M40.332,90.466c0,0-39.911,76.119-2.691,87.83
    c37.22,11.71,78.923-46.844,56.054-78.462C70.826,68.216,40.332,90.466,40.332,90.466z"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P6t2B/

Comment: Doesn't that code work fine?

Comment: i want to select path and i want to apply color for selected path

Comment: Your code does that though. You select the path with the button, and it gets colored...

Comment: Are you talking about the border?

Comment: It doesn't work in StackOverflow as you didn't load jQuery. It works on your fiddle as-is.

Comment: i want to select a path using mouse click and i want apply a color

Comment: See in this link svg path selected by a select menu, i want to select a path in svg using mouse click and i want to apply color 
http://matthewrea.com/work/svgColorPicker/

Comment: @NaveenKumarThippirishetty  you wan to apply color on path border or fill  whole your path area ? as per your fiddle fill  color is working fine

Comment: @NaveenKumarThippirishetty yes. refer this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Comment: happy to help you. why your question on hold .  as that user to change question status

Comment: thank you, i dont know why it is in hold ? what should i do