# d3.js - filling `image` from pattern shrinks the image size

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

[image: shrinked image]I created a circle. i would like to fill the circle with one of my circled image. for this i created a patter and appended a image in it.

after i `fill` the pattern, the image is not the right size here. what is the issue? any one correct me please?

**or any one show me the correct way to fill the image to a circle?**

i commented the information along the code for details:

```
patterns : function () {

        this.svgElement
            .append('pattern')
                .attr({
                    id:'progImage',
                    width:180,
                    height:88,
                    x:0,
                    y:0
                })
            .append('image')
                .attr({
                    x:0,
                    y:0,
                    width:180, //width
                    height:88, //height of image
                    'xlink:href':"images/programme_up.png" //image
                });

    },

    createSvg : function () {
        var that = this;
        this.svgElement = d3.select(this.container)
            .append('svg')
            .attr({
                id:'dashBoard',
                width:this.svgWidth,
                height:this.svgHeight,
                'perserveAspectRatio' :'xMinYMin none',
                viewBox:"0 0 "+this.svgWidth+" "+this.svgHeight
        });
    },

    dashBoard : function () {
        this.svgElement
            .append('circle')
            .attr({
                r: 135,
                cx:this.svgWidth/2,
                cy:this.svgHeight/3,
                fill:'url(#progImage)', //filling here. but the bg is very small..why
                stroke:'white',
                'stroke-width':1
            });
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Actually i require this should be my output:

[image: What i require]

Comment: What's the rendered HTML? and why are you using that javascript library? this is simple SVG stuff.

Comment: Ok, can you show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3798797/4711865

Comment: But around the circle i require to wrap text, is it possible?

Comment: Can you look my `update` on my question. can you show me the correct way to reproduce that? a) adding image to circle, b) adding text to cirlce c) adding events to circle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j2sqknsf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/j2sqknsf/2/ - You can get this done much simpler using just CSS...

If you want to add events to the circle use jQuery:

```
$('svg').on('YOUR_EVENT',function() {

});
```

Comment: How to wrap the text around the circle. can you look my update on my question?

Comment: This explains is far better than I could: https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/