# How to overlap two SVG images?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

So I have two SVG images that I've created in Photoshop. The images have all the correct dimensions to align next to one another however, when I export them out they don't overlap. Below are the two images (sorry for the sizes) :

[image]

[image]

And I've exported them out as SVGs then placed the code within my `index.html` page. That looks like :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="600" height="862" viewBox="0 0 600 862">
  <image xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQIA ..." />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="600" height="862" viewBox="0 0 600 862">
  <image xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA8EAAAT7CAMAAACJ ..." />
</svg>
```

Sorry, I had to create a gist as my images are base64 encoded so they're huge :

[full code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65aa328bb9ceb0f20039)

Question: The background is transparent in Photoshop. But they overlap one another to the point one hides the other. How can I get my two SVG images to overlap one another but both be visible?

Comment: Your svgs are just acting as wrappers for a couple of PNGs? If you drew the  images as vectors you would be able to control stroke and fill with CSS.  Otherwise you would eb better of just using the pngs...

Comment: This will save just fine in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrdWx)

Comment: @flemcito basically yeah. I've tried PNGs but they don't align next to one another. As in, one image as a bottom triangle, then the other images as the top triangle. So I though SVGs might be the way to go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that both shapes are in *seperate svg elements*. So they can't overlap with the default svg positioning. You could make them overlay with absolute, relative or fixed positioning but that would be overkill and complicated for such simple shapes. Another approach would be to export both of them in the same file **BUT** :

For such a simple shape, you can use an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) with 2 [polygon elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon). Simple, much shorter and "human readable" :

```css
svg{width:30%; height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 60">
  <polygon points="0 0 50 0 50 5 0 50" fill="#C000FF"/>
  <polygon points="0 50 50 5 50 60 0 60" fill="#803698"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You even could use a rectangle for the lighter one, so the shape will be even less complex.

Comment: yes @AntiHeadshot or even no element at all and use the `background` CSS property on the svg element but I think for the sake of the question, this approach is more "understandable"

Comment: I have a lot of different images. Based `onClick` I toggle them off and on. The background purple was just for simplicity sake and because i've not found the best images i'm using yet

Comment: I have one full image. You select a button I then have two triangle images as shown above. You then click another and it removes the bottom triangle and replaces with two smaller triangles. All of the are images are will be exported out as triangles. I'm unfamiliar SVGs so I though the only way to get two triangle images side by side was via svgs

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI I am having a hard time understanding what you want exactly. With SVG you can clip images with any shape, maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with SVGs all that much. What you have there, but instead of the fill being colour. It being a background image.

Comment: I tried adding the background image. But it stretches my images so I opted away. I may of just been doing it wrong

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI ok, if you want to fill and SVG element (polygon, path...) you can use a pattern element. This approach is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)