# How to overlap two SVG vectors without using inline SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, overlap, vivus

I have two SVG vectors that I have overlapped by using CSS. See [here](http://codepen.io/xachu4u/pen/qNqLpK). The shapes are as follows:

```
  <svg id="path1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px"   >
    <path
       id="path120"
       d="m273 82c-8.5 0.3-15 0.7-14.5 0.9 0.6 0.2 1.8 0.2 2.9 0.1 1.2-0.1 1.6 0.2 1 1.1-0.5 0.9-0.2 1 0.9 0.6 0.9-0.3 2.7-0.2 3.9 0.3 2.1 0.8 2.2 0.9 0.3 1.1-1.1 0.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 0-1.8-0.3-1.6 1.4 0.4 3 1.1 1 1.4 1 0.9 0.1-0.5-0.8 0.1-1.2 1.8-1.2 1.6 0 2.6-0.6 2.6-1.4 0-1 1.2-1.3 4.7-1 5.6 0.4 8.1-0.9 3.3-1.7-2.6-0.5-1.8-0.6 3-0.7 3.6 0 7 0.4 7.7 0.9 0.6 0.6 1.4 0.6 1.7 0.1s2.5-0.7 4.9-0.6c3.2 0.2 4.4-0.1 4.4-1.2 0-0.8-0.7-1.4-1.4-1.4-0.9 0-1.1 0.5-0.7 1.2 0.5 0.9 0.2 0.9-0.9-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-1.7-0.1 0 1-0.4 1-1.6-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-2.5 0.2-0.6 0.9-1.2 1-1.6 0.4-0.5-0.6-6.5-0.8-16.3-0.5zm-2.3 1.6c-0.3 0.3-1.2 0.4-1.9 0.1-0.8-0.3-0.5-0.6 0.6-0.6 1.1-0.1 1.7 0.2 1.3 0.5z" />

   </svg>

  <svg id="path2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px" >
    <path
       id="path126"
       d="m230 83.1c-4.7 0.3-8 0.6-7.5 0.7 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.7-0.8 1.3-0.9 0.6-2.6 0.8-3.6 0.4-1.1-0.3-2.2-0.2-2.5 0.4-0.6 0.9-10.2 2.7-12.1 2.2s-20.6 0.8-21.4 1.5c-0.2 0.1 8 0.3 18.1 0.3s19.2 0.3 20.1 0.7c1 0.3 1.7 0.1 1.7-0.5s1.5-1.1 3.3-1.2c1.7 0 4.1-0.5 5.2-1 1.5-0.7 1.2-0.8-1.5-0.4-7.1 1.1-15.6 1.5-13 0.6 1.4-0.5 3.7-0.9 5.3-1 1.5-0.1 2.7-0.7 2.7-1.4 0-0.9 2.5-1.2 8.9-1.2 4.9 0 9.3 0.3 9.7 0.7 0.4 0.5-0.4 0.8-1.9 0.8-1.4 0-2.8 0.4-3.1 0.8-0.9 1.5 5.3 0 6.6-1.6 1-1.2 1-1.4 0.1-0.8-0.7 0.4-1.3 0.2-1.3-0.3 0-1.3 1.7-1.4 2.4-0.2 0.4 0.5 1.4 0.8 2.4 0.6 0.9-0.2 2.7-0.4 4-0.4 1.2-0.1 2.2-0.5 2.2-1 0-1-9.9-1-24 0z" />

   </svg>
```

If I change the CSS by removing the `position:absolute` (check the following), then they become two separate shapes. They don't overlap (stay adjacent in this case) anymore.

```
* {
    /* position: absolute; */
}
    #path1{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#path2{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

In this question: [How to overlap two SVG images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397065/how-to-overlap-two-svg-images) , it says CSS is one solution or I could use them both inside a single SVG tag (inline SVG).

1. I can't use CSS; because I need to place the shapes in another HTML page. There if I keep `position: absolute`, it creates all sorts of mess as you can imagine.
2. I can't use inline SVG; because I am trying to animate the shapes using [Vivus](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus). This JS library requires both shapes to be inside a separate SVG tag. So I need to keep the shapes in two different SVG tags to make them animate separately.

Is there any other genius hack to this problem? 
(Without CSS or inline SVG)

Comment: I've no idea why having a JS function to be called on each image separately would preclude them from being inline. The question is rather unclear especially as all positioning in html is via CSS so if you can't use CSS you pretty much can't do anything in html.

Comment: @RobertLongson , the JS library requires the shapes to be in an SVG tag. I need two animations, not a single one. Having them inline means I have only one SVG tag and hence only one animation. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please remove the downvote

Comment: Inline here doesn't mean what you think it does. Inline means included in the page with the HTML. Ie. as opposed to embedded via `<img>`, `<object>` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is restrict the application of the `position: absolute` by restricting that behaviour to one page and not the other.

For example in the snippet below, the SVGs in `<div class="draw">` are overlapped, but the ones in `<div class="draw2">` are not.

```css
.draw {
    height: 250px;
}
.draw svg {
 position: absolute;
}

.path1{
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
}
.path2{
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 50px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.draw2 .path1,
.draw2 .path2 {
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="draw">
  <svg class="path1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px"   >
    <path
       id="path120"
       d="m273 82c-8.5 0.3-15 0.7-14.5 0.9 0.6 0.2 1.8 0.2 2.9 0.1 1.2-0.1 1.6 0.2 1 1.1-0.5 0.9-0.2 1 0.9 0.6 0.9-0.3 2.7-0.2 3.9 0.3 2.1 0.8 2.2 0.9 0.3 1.1-1.1 0.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 0-1.8-0.3-1.6 1.4 0.4 3 1.1 1 1.4 1 0.9 0.1-0.5-0.8 0.1-1.2 1.8-1.2 1.6 0 2.6-0.6 2.6-1.4 0-1 1.2-1.3 4.7-1 5.6 0.4 8.1-0.9 3.3-1.7-2.6-0.5-1.8-0.6 3-0.7 3.6 0 7 0.4 7.7 0.9 0.6 0.6 1.4 0.6 1.7 0.1s2.5-0.7 4.9-0.6c3.2 0.2 4.4-0.1 4.4-1.2 0-0.8-0.7-1.4-1.4-1.4-0.9 0-1.1 0.5-0.7 1.2 0.5 0.9 0.2 0.9-0.9-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-1.7-0.1 0 1-0.4 1-1.6-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-2.5 0.2-0.6 0.9-1.2 1-1.6 0.4-0.5-0.6-6.5-0.8-16.3-0.5zm-2.3 1.6c-0.3 0.3-1.2 0.4-1.9 0.1-0.8-0.3-0.5-0.6 0.6-0.6 1.1-0.1 1.7 0.2 1.3 0.5z" />

   </svg>

  <svg class="path2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px" >
    <path
       id="path126"
       d="m230 83.1c-4.7 0.3-8 0.6-7.5 0.7 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.7-0.8 1.3-0.9 0.6-2.6 0.8-3.6 0.4-1.1-0.3-2.2-0.2-2.5 0.4-0.6 0.9-10.2 2.7-12.1 2.2s-20.6 0.8-21.4 1.5c-0.2 0.1 8 0.3 18.1 0.3s19.2 0.3 20.1 0.7c1 0.3 1.7 0.1 1.7-0.5s1.5-1.1 3.3-1.2c1.7 0 4.1-0.5 5.2-1 1.5-0.7 1.2-0.8-1.5-0.4-7.1 1.1-15.6 1.5-13 0.6 1.4-0.5 3.7-0.9 5.3-1 1.5-0.1 2.7-0.7 2.7-1.4 0-0.9 2.5-1.2 8.9-1.2 4.9 0 9.3 0.3 9.7 0.7 0.4 0.5-0.4 0.8-1.9 0.8-1.4 0-2.8 0.4-3.1 0.8-0.9 1.5 5.3 0 6.6-1.6 1-1.2 1-1.4 0.1-0.8-0.7 0.4-1.3 0.2-1.3-0.3 0-1.3 1.7-1.4 2.4-0.2 0.4 0.5 1.4 0.8 2.4 0.6 0.9-0.2 2.7-0.4 4-0.4 1.2-0.1 2.2-0.5 2.2-1 0-1-9.9-1-24 0z" />

   </svg>

</div>

<div class="draw2">
  <svg class="path1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px"   >
    <path
       id="path120"
       d="m273 82c-8.5 0.3-15 0.7-14.5 0.9 0.6 0.2 1.8 0.2 2.9 0.1 1.2-0.1 1.6 0.2 1 1.1-0.5 0.9-0.2 1 0.9 0.6 0.9-0.3 2.7-0.2 3.9 0.3 2.1 0.8 2.2 0.9 0.3 1.1-1.1 0.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 0-1.8-0.3-1.6 1.4 0.4 3 1.1 1 1.4 1 0.9 0.1-0.5-0.8 0.1-1.2 1.8-1.2 1.6 0 2.6-0.6 2.6-1.4 0-1 1.2-1.3 4.7-1 5.6 0.4 8.1-0.9 3.3-1.7-2.6-0.5-1.8-0.6 3-0.7 3.6 0 7 0.4 7.7 0.9 0.6 0.6 1.4 0.6 1.7 0.1s2.5-0.7 4.9-0.6c3.2 0.2 4.4-0.1 4.4-1.2 0-0.8-0.7-1.4-1.4-1.4-0.9 0-1.1 0.5-0.7 1.2 0.5 0.9 0.2 0.9-0.9-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-1.7-0.1 0 1-0.4 1-1.6-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-2.5 0.2-0.6 0.9-1.2 1-1.6 0.4-0.5-0.6-6.5-0.8-16.3-0.5zm-2.3 1.6c-0.3 0.3-1.2 0.4-1.9 0.1-0.8-0.3-0.5-0.6 0.6-0.6 1.1-0.1 1.7 0.2 1.3 0.5z" />

   </svg>

  <svg class="path2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px" >
    <path
       id="path126"
       d="m230 83.1c-4.7 0.3-8 0.6-7.5 0.7 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.7-0.8 1.3-0.9 0.6-2.6 0.8-3.6 0.4-1.1-0.3-2.2-0.2-2.5 0.4-0.6 0.9-10.2 2.7-12.1 2.2s-20.6 0.8-21.4 1.5c-0.2 0.1 8 0.3 18.1 0.3s19.2 0.3 20.1 0.7c1 0.3 1.7 0.1 1.7-0.5s1.5-1.1 3.3-1.2c1.7 0 4.1-0.5 5.2-1 1.5-0.7 1.2-0.8-1.5-0.4-7.1 1.1-15.6 1.5-13 0.6 1.4-0.5 3.7-0.9 5.3-1 1.5-0.1 2.7-0.7 2.7-1.4 0-0.9 2.5-1.2 8.9-1.2 4.9 0 9.3 0.3 9.7 0.7 0.4 0.5-0.4 0.8-1.9 0.8-1.4 0-2.8 0.4-3.1 0.8-0.9 1.5 5.3 0 6.6-1.6 1-1.2 1-1.4 0.1-0.8-0.7 0.4-1.3 0.2-1.3-0.3 0-1.3 1.7-1.4 2.4-0.2 0.4 0.5 1.4 0.8 2.4 0.6 0.9-0.2 2.7-0.4 4-0.4 1.2-0.1 2.2-0.5 2.2-1 0-1-9.9-1-24 0z" />

   </svg>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what you mean exactly by "overlap".  Or what exactly your restrictions are. If the SVGs are not inlined then they effectively become the same as if they were PNGs or JPEGs. Overlapping them is just a matter of using CSS positioning.

If you just need to draw something that contains both paths, then you can just combine them in one SVG.

```html
<svg id="path1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="120px">
    <path
       id="path120"
       d="m273 82c-8.5 0.3-15 0.7-14.5 0.9 0.6 0.2 1.8 0.2 2.9 0.1 1.2-0.1 1.6 0.2 1 1.1-0.5 0.9-0.2 1 0.9 0.6 0.9-0.3 2.7-0.2 3.9 0.3 2.1 0.8 2.2 0.9 0.3 1.1-1.1 0.1-2.6 0.1-3.2 0-1.8-0.3-1.6 1.4 0.4 3 1.1 1 1.4 1 0.9 0.1-0.5-0.8 0.1-1.2 1.8-1.2 1.6 0 2.6-0.6 2.6-1.4 0-1 1.2-1.3 4.7-1 5.6 0.4 8.1-0.9 3.3-1.7-2.6-0.5-1.8-0.6 3-0.7 3.6 0 7 0.4 7.7 0.9 0.6 0.6 1.4 0.6 1.7 0.1s2.5-0.7 4.9-0.6c3.2 0.2 4.4-0.1 4.4-1.2 0-0.8-0.7-1.4-1.4-1.4-0.9 0-1.1 0.5-0.7 1.2 0.5 0.9 0.2 0.9-0.9-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-1.7-0.1 0 1-0.4 1-1.6-0.1-1.3-1-1.7-1-2.5 0.2-0.6 0.9-1.2 1-1.6 0.4-0.5-0.6-6.5-0.8-16.3-0.5zm-2.3 1.6c-0.3 0.3-1.2 0.4-1.9 0.1-0.8-0.3-0.5-0.6 0.6-0.6 1.1-0.1 1.7 0.2 1.3 0.5z" />

    <path
       id="path126"
       d="m230 83.1c-4.7 0.3-8 0.6-7.5 0.7 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.7-0.8 1.3-0.9 0.6-2.6 0.8-3.6 0.4-1.1-0.3-2.2-0.2-2.5 0.4-0.6 0.9-10.2 2.7-12.1 2.2s-20.6 0.8-21.4 1.5c-0.2 0.1 8 0.3 18.1 0.3s19.2 0.3 20.1 0.7c1 0.3 1.7 0.1 1.7-0.5s1.5-1.1 3.3-1.2c1.7 0 4.1-0.5 5.2-1 1.5-0.7 1.2-0.8-1.5-0.4-7.1 1.1-15.6 1.5-13 0.6 1.4-0.5 3.7-0.9 5.3-1 1.5-0.1 2.7-0.7 2.7-1.4 0-0.9 2.5-1.2 8.9-1.2 4.9 0 9.3 0.3 9.7 0.7 0.4 0.5-0.4 0.8-1.9 0.8-1.4 0-2.8 0.4-3.1 0.8-0.9 1.5 5.3 0 6.6-1.6 1-1.2 1-1.4 0.1-0.8-0.7 0.4-1.3 0.2-1.3-0.3 0-1.3 1.7-1.4 2.4-0.2 0.4 0.5 1.4 0.8 2.4 0.6 0.9-0.2 2.7-0.4 4-0.4 1.2-0.1 2.2-0.5 2.2-1 0-1-9.9-1-24 0z" />
</svg>
```