# Images not Generating D3

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js

Here is my problem. My graph currently looks like this: [image] Which is dandy. However, I want the black squares on top to be filled with pictures. Luckily I have a CSS file that has pictures linked with classes. I also have a JSON file that contains all the class names. All those class names are assigned to the squares and I can see the picture in the inspect element on Chrome. The only issue is the pictures don't appear in the square. (Also my axises broke, but that is secondary concern). [CSS](https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/translationperfect/branding/css/photo-id.css?v=5-19-2016), [JSON](https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/intgraphs/data.01.json)

This is where I'm assigning classes and creating the rectangles.

```
svg.selectAll(".div")
    .data(data.chartData, function(d){return d.vNm;})
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d){
        return x(d.vNm);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return (y(d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){
            return sum + d.amount;
        }, 0))) - 64.5;
    })
    .attr("width", 43)
    .attr("height", 43)
    .attr("class", function(d){return d.vId;})
    .style("fill", function(d) { return segColor(d.data.type); });
```

Comment: please show us some examples of your code

Comment: @NoamHacker you need more?

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin You are using SVG, so this is not possible. Setting a background image via CSS only works on "regular html" elements. So either you have to take the SVG approach to background images ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image) for example), or perhaps you can figure out how to use "regular html" to render your chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to solve your problem is to use `html` elements like `div` for the images above the chart instead of `svg` elements, so you can use the full power of css.

Luckily you don't need to calculate the position of those html elements by yourself, there are some libraries that help you **position** the images correctly above the bars in the chart.

Check out https://popper.js.org/ for example, you can just call its API for each **bar** you render using `d3.js`:

```
 var popper = new Popper(barElement, onPopper, {
        placement: 'top'
    });
```

Comment: Can I use the CSS images in the poppers?

Comment: they are regular html elements so any css would work on them.

Comment: And how would I assign a class to it

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements do not follow exactly the same CSS rules as typical HTML elements.

In your case, `background-image` doesn't work.

The least painful way to achieve the effect would be to embed an `<image>` tag after the `<rect>`:

```
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,...">
```

It means that you have to modify your JSON to store the image's base64 data in there instead of CSS.