# How to extend background from parent square to circle child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a pattern that needs to repeat itself across element1 to element 2 without user noticing the transition. Basically i need element1 and element2 to blend together, any idea how to approach this problem?
i was thinking about using javascript and calculating background offset, but i am thinking its 2016 there has to be some better way maybe including css maybe svg, tbh i am looking for someone to push me in right direction.
basicaly i have pic 1 and need to contrusct pic2 from html to be responsive. element 1 streches across screen with fixed height but variable width and element 2 is on fixed position. with fixed height and width.
[image: image representaation 1]

[image]

Comment: this seems to be the way to go 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)