# Overlay image/gif with partially transparent layer

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I want to create something like the following for my react-native project:

[image]

So I basically want to have an image or a gif and I want to put a transparent text with a colored background on top of it. In the above seen case, it is transparent text with a white background.

I can't find a way to do it.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No need for JavaScript in this case, CSS will do

Comment: See also http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

Comment: @Pekka웃 I added stuff. It is for a react-native project

Comment: Well, that changes things. Reopening

Comment: That's going to be more difficult. Best bet IMO would be SVG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image but no way to do that with dynamic text I think