# Highchart.js: use bootstrap glyphicons instead of symbols on contextbutton

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, glyphicons

How can i use bootstrap glyphicons instead of "regular" symbols in the contextbuttons of Highcharts. Going to exporting > buttons > contextButton.
I have added some glyphicon in the className propery, but the symbol shows up instead. Is there any way to override this?

Here is an example JSON object for Highcharts:

```
{
"chart": {
    "type": "column",
    "renderTo": "periodChart"
},
"title": {
    "text": "Verkoop per periode"
},
"xAxis": {
    "categories": ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
},
"yAxis": {
    "title": {
        "text": "Aantal verkochte producten"
    }
},
"exporting": {
    "buttons": {
        "contextButton": {
            "align": "right",
            "symbol": "menu",
            "height": 22,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 0,
            "x": 0,
            "className": "glyphicon glyphicon-print",
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
},
"series": [{
    "borderColor": "#555",
    "data": [{
        "name": "2015",
        "y": 6121.0
    }, {
        "name": "2016",
        "y": 6172.0
    }, {
        "name": "2017",
        "y": 4943.0
    }],
    "name": "Aantallen  per jaar (P/s)"
}]
}
```

I have added the following packages to my html, along with bootstrap and jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Edit: when i leave the symbol property empty ("") then nothing shows up. Not using the property at all will result in the default "menu" symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The post before the edit contained only the information how to add a regular image as a background to the context button which wasn't the actual answer for this question.

Here I used glyphicon as a charcter in the text of te button: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/LoLtm8bn/

I haven't found a way to completely disable the symbol in the context button. The workaround for this is to hide it but the space reserved for it still remains there.

I ended up using the approach from **Full text button** example in this API record: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.text (`contextButton` disabled, `exportButton` used instead).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/np80zf58/

**END OF EDIT**

---

Context button is an **SVG** element so you need to use `defs`pattern for this:

**JS:**

```
events: {
  load: function() {

    var chart = this,
      renderer = chart.renderer;
    var pattern = renderer.createElement('pattern').add(renderer.defs).attr({
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      id: "image1",
      patternContentUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'
    });

    renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png', 0, 0, 24, 24).add(pattern);

  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
// hide the default symbol
.highcharts-button-symbol {
  display: none
}

// use a new one
.highcharts-button-box {
  fill: url(#image1)
}
```

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2cpvuydd/

---

**SO related question:** [Fill SVG path element with a background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

**Highcharts docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

**Highcharts API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: Is the example supposed to display a Sun insead of the menu image? Also this still doesn't answer my question, I want to use glyphicons insead of svg.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I edited my answer and fixed the original fiddle (the one with the sun icon).

Comment: Sorry for responding late. The edit is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.