# How to add image inside svg path?

Tags: css, svg, frontend

I want to add an image to SVG path. I tried at some level but it's a half-baked code and image is not taking a proper shape of SVG.

Here's the HTML for that:

```
<div class="top-fold">
 <div class="curve-img" id="shapeContainer">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1280" height="564" viewBox="0 0 1280 564" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <defs>
                <rect id="bg-a" width="1280" height="575"/>
                <linearGradient id="bg-b" x1="50%" x2="71.552%" y1="-4.763%" y2="100%">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FAFBFC"/>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EBF3F9"/>
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <mask id="bg-c" fill="#fff">
                  <use xlink:href="#bg-a"/>
                </mask>
                <path fill="url(#bg-b)" d="M0,0 L1280,0 L1280,465.166826 C1282.16971,484.337191 1283.83637,494.281583 1285,495 C1358.96463,540.665449 1275.63125,544.202225 1034,558.75895 C786.666667,573.659188 442,550.377565 0,488.914081 L0,0 Z" mask="url(#bg-c)"/>
              </g>
            </svg>

    </div><!-- curve-img end -->
  </div> <!-- top fold end -->
```

Here's the CSS for that.

```
.top-fold {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
 }

.curve-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

#shapeContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.2),
      rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.8)
    ),
    url(https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#shapeContainer svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 150%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 200px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 200%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 100px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 300%;
  }
}
```

Here's the codepen link for your reference. https://codepen.io/enworl/pen/xPyMxL

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image. I think the accepted answer will help you

Comment: Using a mask should work. However it is not clear what you want the final result to look like. Can you post a mockup image for us?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @PaulLeBeau I'm trying to achieve this. Please check this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnhmP8aSKOMg9O0zWvsMHLJWf381jRW_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

You probably did not like the asymmetric form of the patch, that's how it looks like you.

[image]

I changed the form of the patch, but really, as Paul says, you need a layout from you, what you want to get.

[image]

New patch code:

```
<path d="M4 4 1278 0c1 137 0 330 0 420 0 89-304 140-639 139C399 557 1 518 3 427 4 355 4 4 4 4Z" fill="grey"/>
```

Your application with the new patch code:

```css
.top-fold {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
 }

.curve-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

#shapeContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.2),
      rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.8)
    ),
    url(https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#shapeContainer svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 150%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 200px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 200%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 100px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-fold">
 <div class="curve-img" id="shapeContainer">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1280" height="564" viewBox="0 0 1280 564" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <defs>
                <rect id="bg-a" width="1280" height="575"/>
                <linearGradient id="bg-b" x1="50%" x2="71.552%" y1="-4.763%" y2="100%">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FAFBFC"/>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EBF3F9"/>
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <mask id="bg-c" fill="#fff">
                  <use xlink:href="#bg-a"/>
                </mask>
                <path fill="url(#bg-b)" d="M4 4 1278 0c1 137 0 330 0 420 0 89-304 140-639 139C399 557 1 518 3 427 4 355 4 4 4 4Z" mask="url(#bg-c)"/>
              </g>
            </svg>

    </div><!-- curve-img end -->
  </div> <!-- top fold end -->
```

It is necessary to remove vertical strips, somehow change the form, design? We are waiting for your layout and description.

**Without vertical stripes**

```css
.top-fold {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
 }

.curve-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

#shapeContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.2),
      rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.8)
    ),
    url(https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#shapeContainer svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 150%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 200px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 200%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 100px) {
  #shapeContainer {
    background-size: auto 300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-fold">
 <div class="curve-img" id="shapeContainer">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1280" height="564" viewBox="0 0 1280 564" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <defs>
                <rect id="bg-a" width="1280" height="575"/>
                <linearGradient id="bg-b" x1="50%" x2="71.552%" y1="-4.763%" y2="100%">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FAFBFC"/>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EBF3F9"/>
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <mask id="bg-c" fill="#fff">
                  <use xlink:href="#bg-a"/>
                </mask>
                <path fill="url(#bg-b)" d="M-0.4 0.4 1282 0c0.9 137.1-0.5 330.3-0.5 419.6 0 89.3-307.6 140.5-643.3 138.7C398.7 557.1-2.5 518.2-1.1 426.8 0.1 354.6-0.4 0.4-0.4 0.4Z" mask="url(#bg-c)"/>
              </g>
            </svg>

    </div><!-- curve-img end -->
  </div> <!-- top fold end -->
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot in you sample, that I'm not sure about.  A lot of it is unrelated to the main thrust of your question about having a mask with a curved bottom.

Anyway, creating the mask is actually quite simple.  See the example below.

```css
.top-fold {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
 }

.curve-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#shapeContainer svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-fold">
  <div class="curve-img" id="shapeContainer">
    <svg>
      <defs>
        <mask id="bg-c" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <path fill="white"
                transform="scale(0.000781, 0.001742)"
                d="M0,0 L1280,0 L1280,465.166826 C1282.16971,484.337191 1283.83637,494.281583 1285,495 C1358.96463,540.665449 1275.63125,544.202225 1034,558.75895 C786.666667,573.659188 442,550.377565 0,488.914081 L0,0 Z"/>
        </mask>
      </defs>

      <image xlink:href="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg"
             width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" mask="url(#bg-c)"/>
    </svg>

  </div><!-- curve-img end -->
</div> <!-- top fold end -->
```

Note that there are still some quirks with applying masks to HTML content, so for now, the easiest approach is to put the image in the SVG instead.

I have removed the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio="none"` from the SVG as we want it to scale up with its parent without distorting the image.

We are also switching the mask to use `objectBoundingBox` units, so that it fits the image no matter what size it ends up as.

---

If you need the orange gradient wash on top, you can do it like this.

```css
.top-fold {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
 }

.curve-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#shapeContainer svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-fold">
  <div class="curve-img" id="shapeContainer">
    <svg>
      <defs>
        <mask id="bg-c" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <path fill="white"
                transform="scale(0.000781, 0.001742)"
                d="M0,0 L1280,0 L1280,465.166826 C1282.16971,484.337191 1283.83637,494.281583 1285,495 C1358.96463,540.665449 1275.63125,544.202225 1034,558.75895 C786.666667,573.659188 442,550.377565 0,488.914081 L0,0 Z"/>
        </mask>
        <linearGradient id="bg-b" x2="0" y2="1">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.2)"/>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(255, 159, 63, 0.8)"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>

      <g mask="url(#bg-c)">
        <image xlink:href="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg"
               width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bg-b)"/>
      </g>       
    </svg>

  </div><!-- curve-img end -->
</div> <!-- top fold end -->
```