# Image z-index onhover mutiple SVG polygon

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on SVG here my concept is I have two images `.overlap` with each other and using svg polygon I made five different triangles. my aim to achieve first overlay complete image display and when hover on triangles shapes background `.box` box image needs to display. 
This is my initial code before giving an overlay image.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}

polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: #ffffff;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 100">
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Now I have added overlay image need to come above the `.box` image and `polygons` shapes. Now, hover I want to display .box image in a current polygon shape like this 
[image: iamge]

Code here

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}

polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: #ffffff;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: transparent;
}

.overlay:hover polygon {
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="box">

  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 100">
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out this on hover we need to adjust the z-indexes of the divs and polygon fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would adjust the code of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56562302/8620333) like below:

```css
.box {
  width:450px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/1000/800) center/cover;
}
.box > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  opacity:0;
}
.box > div:nth-child(1) {
  clip-path:polygon(20% 0,80% 0, 50% 100%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(2) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 20% 0,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(3) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 0,80% 0,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:nth-child(4) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(5) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 100%,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/90/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/102/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800)"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an illustration to show you the different points used in `clip-path`

[image]

With the same image:

```css
.box {
  width:450px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/1000/800) center/cover;
}
.box > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  opacity:0;
}
.box > div:nth-child(1) {
  clip-path:polygon(20% 0,80% 0, 50% 100%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(2) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 20% 0,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(3) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 0,80% 0,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:nth-child(4) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(5) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 100%,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly this is what I need only the point is in all polygon same image I want to add if the add individually same image I need to adjust image positions. and all can you suggest me about this only one image just view in the different shapes of a triangle.

Comment: @Husna simply use the same image for all the div, no need to adjust anyhing else ... I added a different image using inline style, simply remove this and use the image in the CSS (check the update)

Comment: ok. I really appreciate you to the time you have given here. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Temani's CSS only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576696/3702797) is great, however, beware this is [still not supported in Safari nor in IE/Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility).

For these browsers, you'll need to fallback on SVG, which also implements a `<clipPath>` element.

```css
.overlay {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay use {
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay use:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clip-1'>
      <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-2'>
      <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-3'>
      <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-4'>
      <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-5'>
      <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
      xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-1)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-2)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-3)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-4)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-5)"/>
</svg>
<div class="box"></div>
```

So, yes, it's more verbose, but it should work in every browser since IE9.

Comment: thanks. Here I don't want polygon lines on the image as like Temani output like that can you make changes in your code and remove that lines on image.

Comment: @Husna then it's simpler

Comment: still very thin 1px of the line is coming can you suggest me how to remove those lines. We remove stroke but still from where these lines are coming.

Comment: That's antialising, you'd have to make your polygons a bit larger than necessary (e.g make them bleed one unit in each direction). Sorry I run out of time right now. Ah or actually we can make like Temani: inverse what is hidden

Comment: I edited to use the same technique as Temani: show the slice on hover.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the svg to appear above it's parent div, you could change the attributes of the svg element like below:

```css
   /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
   /*necessary for expanding .box div and svg*/
   /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
   html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
   }
   
   .box {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      
      position: relative;
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      
      /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
      /*I CHANGED HEIGHT TO 100% FOR BOX AS IT WASNT SPANNING THE ENTIRE PAGE - in turn, the "overlay"
      div's background image could be seen...*/
      /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    /*position the svg element relative to its parent so it can be moved up with z-index*/
    /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    svg{
      position:relative;
      z-index:999;
    }

    polygon {
      stroke-width: 1;
      stroke: red;
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    polygon:hover {
      fill: transparent;
    }

    .overlay:hover polygon {
      z-index: 100;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      z-index: 10;
    }
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="box">

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <!--in order to make the svg span the entirety of its parent, I set width and height attributes
  for it to 100%-->
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewbox="0 0 200 100">
    <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50 "
          style="stroke:#000000;"/>
    <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,0 0,0 "
          style="stroke:#000000;"/>
    <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"
          style="stroke:#000000;"/>
    <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"
          style="stroke:#000000;"/>
    <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"
          style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my answer and included the code I used; I hope that it can help

Comment: No initially overlay image has to display.

Comment: Oh, ok I see. Sorry, I had a slight misunderstanding. Give me one sec