# How can i add backgroung image in the following svg?

Tags: css

From this website

```
https://smooth.ie/blogs/news/svg-wavey-transitions-between-sections
```

i generated the following svg

```
<div style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;" class='parent' ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><path d="M213.19,0.00 C152.69,70.06 270.03,70.06 202.98,150.00 L500.00,150.00 L500.00,0.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #08f;"></path></svg></div>
```

the problem is that when i try to add background image for example here on the parent class

```
.parent {
    background-image: url('../../../assets/images/calendar.png');
}
```

then the image is hidden behind the blue color of the svg.How can i 'insert' this image to be on the blue svg color image ?

Answer (score 0):

change the opacity level so the color is lower opacity. something like this perhaps.

background {
backgroundColor:blue,
opacity: 0.5;
}

Comment: i need that hard blue color without the opacity

Answer (score 0):

As name says - it's "background-image" so it always is on the background of selected element.

I suggest that you should make an `<img>` tag in parent element and style it so that `.parent` would have attribute `position: relative` and `img` should have `position: absolute`.
Also remember to set `top` and `left/right` position for `<img>`.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide an example please

Comment: As i understood, when i try what you said, i get separete images

Answer (score 0):

it's Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798797/9017484

You can do it by making the background into a pattern:

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image href="wall.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
```

your code should be something like this:

```
<div style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;" class='parent' >
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <image href="ImageFile.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
<path d="M213.19,0.00 C152.69,70.06 270.03,70.06 202.98,150.00 L500.00,150.00 L500.00,0.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: url(#img1);"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: If i copy paste the code then i dont get the blue color of the svg.I don't know a lot about the svg images,where should i make changes to have the blue svg ?