# SVG element does not appear into body email

Tags: html, sql-server, formatting, sp-send-dbmail

I want to send a mail using sp_send_dbmail in sql server having a svg element inside. But running this test the image does not appear inside the email body

```
DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @HTML = '
<html>
<body>

<svg  height="100" width="100">
  <circle xlink:href="img/test.png" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg> 
 
</body>
</html>
'

EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'infoMessage',
      @recipients = 'ste...',
 
      @subject = '[WARNING] Invoice posted with missing data',
      @body = @html,
      @body_format ='HTML',
      @attach_query_result_as_file =0
```

This is only a test to see if the svg element works. I should integrate it with data queried from db. Do you knwo why it is not working?
Regards

Comment: Well, you have som png image but it is being sent in the email as attachment, or how is the email server supposed to access the image stored on your computer

Comment: You can't fill a svg circle element with an image like this. You either need to create a [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image) or clip an `<image>` element. Besides many email clients still don't support svg