Using `background-image` to fill SVG rect with stipple pattern
I’m able to use background-image with a gradient to generate a stipple pattern for a div (upper square), but I can’t seem to make an SVG element (lower square) use that as a fill.
I don’t want to use a defs or pattern definition as I’m using d3.js to create my SVGs, so ideally I’m looking for a pure CSS solution.


    .stipple {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: white;
      background-image: radial-gradient(black 0.5px, transparent 0.5px),
                        radial-gradient(black 0.5px, transparent 0.5px);
      background-size: 5px 5px;
      background-position: 0 0, 2.5px 2.5px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
  <div class="stipple"></div>
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    <rect width="200" height="200" class="stipple" />
  </svg>




Pretty sure you can't do this without a pattern... that's what it's for.

Please read about SVG patterns

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Thanks to whoever edited my code into a snippet..

Seems like a shame if there isn’t a way to reuse a CSS gradient though (for uniformity of style).

Theoretically, this should be addressed with CSS Fill and Stroke Module Level 3, but it looks as if there has been no work on this for the last four years.

you could define the pattern entirely within CSS as a data URL

In case you rect just serves as a background filling the complete viewBox you could also apply a CSS background the the parent SVG and remove the rect.
